# How to replace a pattern in the middle fo the line, delimited by whitespace (spaces, tabs) and with a certain length?

Tags: notepad++

So for example:

```
+573215836501@gmail.com $2y$12$MTg3MTAwMTY5MTllYzA5NO414qUGtsj7kb7uzIlQbSxjg6nzGHRpC    arleyrua
```

I want to transform it into:

```
+573215836501@gmail.com:arleyrua
```

The middle line segment has 60 characters of all kinds (alphanumeric and symbols) and I want to replace it (including the space behind and after it) with a `:` character.

Comment: Ah so there may be a double or triple space then? My answer should still work with this - I've tested with the new sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match exactly 60 characters (of any kind) between two spaces of arbitrary length (I've added parenthesis for clarity, they are not required):

```
([ \t]+)(.{60})([ \t]+)
```

Breakdown:

```
[ \t]+ matches any number of spaces and tabs
.{60}  matches 60 occurences of any character
()     are there just for visual grouping (in this particular case)
```

Using this as a test case:

```
asdojiajdsa 01234af7890123456789g12345678901234abcd901234567890123456789 zzzzzzcasdaf
fwqiojiofjwif 01234af78901AAAA6789g12345678!!!234abcd901234567890123456789 adsidoqpwpz
qpsppwpqpweqp 0DSF4af7890123456789g12345678901234abcd?01234567890123456789 oixzjioqdq
qpsppwpqpweqp 4324343 oixzjioqdq
```

I get the following result when I replace the regex with `:`

```
asdojiajdsa:zzzzzzcasdaf
fwqiojiofjwif:adsidoqpwpz
qpsppwpqpweqp:oixzjioqdq
qpsppwpqpweqp 4324343 oixzjioqdq
```

Comment: It does not work. https://imgur.com/a/byfVChD

Comment: Are you sure there are 60 characters? Perhaps you can paste a part of the actual data?

Comment: Done, updated with a part of actual data

Comment: @Davyd: are there spaces or tabs before and after the 60 characters?

Comment: Most of them are tabs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format is always:

> any-characters-no-spaces |SPACE| any-characters-no-spaces |SPACE|  any-characters-no-spaces

Put this in find:

> .* 
>   Note that this is |Space|FullStop|Asterisk|Space| - a space in front and behind

And this in replace with:

> : 
>   (Single Colon)

Make sure you have 'Regular Expression' selected

[image]

Comment: It's letters+characters TAB 60 lenght word (letters+ characters) TAB letters+characters

Comment: So for example test!123. 60CHARLENGHTWORD$ somethinghere!!1

Comment: special characters too ::)

Comment: Updated for anycharacters (as long as there's only ever 2 spaces ??) You might want to update the question with these parameters too by the way.

Comment: Updated. Please give it a look again.

Comment: Same - tested with your examples

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\K\h+\S{60}\h+`
- Replace with: `:`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \S+       # 1 or more non spaces
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces (i.e. space or tab)
  \S{60}    # 60 non spaces
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Result for given example:**

```
+573215836501@gmail.com:arleyrua
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]